# Error in the same namespace after an interface extension

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

Good morning guys, I have a little problem.

has a class called "SettingsPage" which extends "PageBase". PageBase "in turn extends both" IPageBase "and" Page ".

When in the graphics page of "SettingsPage" (Xaml) I specify that it is of type PageBase this gives me error.

The error says that "PageBase" does not exist in the same context but the name space is the same.

I put you below the classes competes

PageBase.cs

```
namespace EVS.Pages
{
    public class PageBase : Page, IPagebase
    {
        string IPagebase.Title => "No Title";
    }
    public interface IPagebase 
    {
        String Title { get; }
    }
}
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace EVS.Pages
{
    public sealed partial class SettingsPage :  PageBase
    {
        string Title => "Settings";

        public SettingsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<local:PageBase
    x:Class="EVS.Pages.SettingsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EVS.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</local:PageBase>
```

thanks in advance, at your disposal for further clarification

Comment: Does the app still compile? The designer sometimes is quite unreliable in such scenarios.

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: Could you click Clean solution in the Build menu and then close visual studio and delete the `obj` and `bin` folders in the project folder?

Comment: strange, I had already cleaned the project, now it seems to work, thank you very much

Comment: I will write an answer :-) .

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because of some temporary files that are left out in the `obj` and `bin` folders of the project.

Click `Clean Solution` in the `Build` menu and then close Visual Studio and delete the `obj` and `bin` folders in the project folder.